# How to enable screen timeout in AndEngine?

Tags: android, timeout, screen, andengine

I've just started using AndEngine to create an android game and by the looks of it a Game Activity keeps the screen on by default. The game I'm working on would require the constant focus of the player so there is no need to keep the screen on when no touch input is registered for a long time. So how can I enable screen timeout?

My guess was to use setWakeLockOption, but I couldn't figure out what to pass to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the acquireWakeLock call in BaseGameActivitys onResume method

```
protected synchronized void onResume() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Debug.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onResume" + " @(Thread: '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "')");
        }

        super.onResume();

        //this.acquireWakeLock();
        this.mRenderSurfaceView.onResume();
    }
```